# Dialog vs. '\n'

Tags: linux, shell, dialog

I'm trying to use dialog to show some data, but unfortunatly the data might contain "\n" substring (2 characters: \ and n, and not literal enter character).

It looks that whatever I will do, dialog interprets those \n as literal enter, and breaks the content.

For example you can try:

```
dialog --infobox "a\\nb" 10 10
```

and:

```
echo "a\\nb"
```

Is there any way to disable this \n interpolation, or escape it somehow? I tried with up to 6 \ characters in front of \ but it doesn't help.

Comment: The source code for dialog is here: http://invisible-island.net/dialog/ Look in `util.c`, method `dlg_trim_string`, for the newline handling code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick, however it doesn't seem you can mix both types. You either have "forced" `\n` interpretation, or none at all:

```
dialog --no-nl-expand ...
```

Comment: `Error: Unknown option --no-nl-expand.` - I guess it's a new option in some newer dialog (I'm on 1.1-20100428).

Comment: @depesz - Yes. Get the source from the link I posted below your question. You can compile it yourself to get the newer version with this option.